# Compiling with -g for GDB in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

new to using Makefiles and was wondering how I would include the -g command (and anything else I need) in order to compile my program to be run with gdb. Here is the Makefile I was given. Thanks in advance.

```
  include parallelDefs

COMMON = dataGen.h utils.h IO.h parseCommandLine.h graph.h graphIO.h graphUtils.h parallel.h sequence.h blockRadixSort.h deterministicHash.h transpose.h
GENERATORS = rMatGraph gridGraph powerGraph randLocalGraph addWeights randDoubleVector fromAdjIdx adjToEdgeArray adjElimSelfEdges

.PHONY: all clean
all: $(GENERATORS)

$(COMMON) :
    ln -s ../../common/$@ .

%.o : %.C $(COMMON)
    $(PCC) $(PCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

rMatGraph : rMatGraph.o 
    $(PCC) $(PLFLAGS) -o $@ rMatGraph.o 

gridGraph : gridGraph.o 
    $(PCC) $(PLFLAGS) -o $@ gridGraph.o 

powerGraph : powerGraph.o 
    $(PCC) $(PLFLAGS) -o $@ powerGraph.o 

randLocalGraph : randLocalGraph.o 
    $(PCC) $(PLFLAGS) -o $@ randLocalGraph.o 

addWeights : addWeights.o 
    $(PCC) $(PLFLAGS) -o $@ addWeights.o

fromAdjIdx : fromAdjIdx.o 
    $(PCC) $(PLFLAGS) -o $@ fromAdjIdx.o

randDoubleVector : randDoubleVector.o
    $(PCC) $(PLFLAGS) -o $@ randDoubleVector.o

adjToEdgeArray : adjToEdgeArray.C $(COMMON)
    $(PCC) $(PCFLAGS) $(PLFLAGS) -o $@ adjToEdgeArray.C

adjElimSelfEdges : adjElimSelfEdges.C $(COMMON)
    $(PCC) $(PCFLAGS) $(PLFLAGS) -o $@ adjElimSelfEdges.C

clean :
    rm -f *.o $(GENERATORS)
    make clean -s -C data

cleansrc : 
    make -s clean
    rm -f $(COMMON)
```

Comment: Which targets there need that flag added? All of them?

Comment: Where are `PCC` and `PCFLAGS` are defined? I presume that you should look at `parallelDefs`.

Comment: a blind guess: most commonly followed method, use something along the line of `PCFLAGS += -g`

Comment: Just the randLocalGraph needs the flag

Answer (score 1):

If only `randLocalGraph` should be compiled with the `-g` option, then it will need an explicit rule:

```
randLocalGraph.o: randLocalGraph.C $(COMMON)
        $(PCC) $(PCFLAGS) -g -c randLocalGraph.C -o $@
```

All the other objects will be created using the implicit rule.